# Auctex not displaying pdf correctly using pdftools

Tags: init-file, auctex, pdf

I am using pdftools with AUCTEX so that I can display output within emacs. I am using a windows system with emacs 25.3. However after compilation I get the following:

```
%PDF-1.5
%    
3 0 obj
<<
/Length 2521      
/Filter /FlateDecode
>>
stream
xڭYY 7~ _!`_Z      }k{ q6# 8g k {҇' ۷ E !5 y & W     n  {-ŪH Ld     :  * * ,_  W       *L   ǟ     " > ӏ ֟o }   U 9   F   )RcL b-Y q   ͛? 7R    +j< ~kQ$ 7   t   3X )g  HMg    <  N   "š C    )  FC]Mߺk  k  M ؔ d
```

Also when I start emacs I get the following message:

```
need to build the epdfinfo program. do it now?(y or n)
```

If I answer yes then it asks me the following:

```
Do you have Msys2 installed?
```

It then asks the directory into which this is installed. Not sure what this is or where its installed.

In my unit file I have the following lines:

```
;;latex extra package - additional goodies.
(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook #'latex-extra-mode)
(setq latex-run-command "pdflatex")

;;use pdftools to preview
(pdf-tools-install) ;; start server

 (setq TeX-view-program-selection '((output-pdf "PDF Tools"))
 TeX-view-program-list '(("PDF Tools" TeX-pdf-tools-sync-view))
    TeX-source-correlate-start-server t) ;; not sure if last line is neccessary

;; to have the buffer refresh after compilation
 (add-hook 'TeX-after-compilation-finished-functions
        #'TeX-revert-document-buffer)
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: That looks like the raw pdf file.  Can you view other pdf files successfully?

Comment: @AndrewSwann Yes, its the raw pdf. I tried another pdf (instead of one generated via tex) and same result.

Comment: Edited question to include information on what occurs at emacs startup.

Comment: Which operating system do you have?

Comment: @AndrewSwann Windows 10

Comment: Have you followed instructions at https://github.com/politza/pdf-tools/blob/master/README.org#compilation-and-installation-on-windows?

Comment: @giordano tried to do this. Unfortunately when trying to make pdftools using gnu make, I get the following error:$ make -s
make: emacs: Command not found
Using Emacs
make: emacs: Command not found
make: emacs: Command not found
make: emacs: Command not found
make: cask: Command not found
make: *** [Makefile:44: .cask/] Error 127

Comment: Sorry, I'm not familiar with pdf-tools on windows, but I've the feeling it's not supereasy to install on that platform.

Comment: @giordano yes was not super easy (at least to my knowledge level) but managed to do it - maybe will write what I did as answer for reference by others.

Comment: Would be great!